# Outlook live - spam rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

I am getting spam from an address which changes everyday. Usually in the form

[day][month]@mail[randomnumber]-online.info

eg mars@mail13-online.info or 24fev@mail11-online.info

It happens since years. I have been clearing by mails from spam recently, but I can't block this one. I want to block all the addresses ending by -online.info, or by object (since the object is always the same).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give this a try...

Open up your Rules and alerts and create a new rule.  It should come up with a wizard that looks similar to this...

[image]

I am using **Outlook 2016** so it may look a little different, but the options should be similar.

From there you would check off "*with specific words in the sender's address*"

You would then create the rule to look for "-online.info" and tell it to send emails with that in the address to go to your junk or deleted folder.

This is something that may take a couple tries, so let me know if this helps or if you need more help finding the option.

Comment: I am not able to find any "rules" menu. I am using the website, not the tool so I have no idea if this is even possible. All I have is an options to add addresses in a block list.

Comment: No problem, give that a shot and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Yeah it works. It instantly goes into spam folder. Thank you again!

Comment: @Aulaulz no problem!